# Textmining - Find words that begin with a prefix

Tags: r, rvest

I have a column with 50 000 "cells" which contain paragraphs. I want to search into each "cell" if exist any word  that begin with "surv" ( such as survive, survivor, ..)and if that exist give me a value =1, if that doesn't exist give me a value =0.

Comment: If you end up wanting to find the word itself, you can look into `regmatches` and `regexec`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `grepl` and a regular expression

```
column = c("I survived the storm", "I surfed", 
    "Follow the curve", "The survival of the fittest")

as.numeric(grepl("\\bsurv", column)) 
[1] 1 0 0 1
```

If you also want to catch "Survivor",  you can add `ignore.case = TRUE`